# Android - EditText setError not showing until EditText is blurred and focused again

Tags: android, error-handling, android-edittext

[image: This is what should happen, without the need of blur and focus password EditText]

Hello,

I'm implementing a Login activity for my application. I make a server request so as to know if the user/password is correct. If not, I would like to show an error on the Password EditText.

My code for that is the following:

```
public void onLoginError() {
    inPassword.setError("Error...");
}
```

This function is called when the request returns an invalid user/password result.

The problem is that the error is not shown until I deselect the Password EditText and focus it again.

Why is this happening? Do I have to update renderer or something like that because it is an Async behavior?

Thanks in advance.!

Answer (score 1):

You should give focus to your `EditText`:

```
inPassword.requestFocus();
inPassword.setError("Error...");
```

or:

```
inPassword.setError("Error...");
inPassword.requestFocus();
```

Comment: No, that's not working. It's related to making an async request and then trying to set the error when the promise is resolved.

Comment: @josec89 try reversing the order, first set error and then request focus

Comment: Yep, I tried all that. It's not related to that. When I make the server requestI user a Promise (from JDeferred) and maybe it's not the same thread or something like that, because it works perfectly if I set the error before the request callback

Comment: @josec89 Maybe first set error to null and right after call remaining sequence? If it was called from wrong thread you would get exception.

Answer (score 0):

I am using JDeferred and there is a module for android that uses the UI thread so as to change view.